# What kind of datatype will hold 3000000^2 in C++?

Tags: c++

What will hold something like 3000000^2 without overflow?

Comment: A 64-bit integer. `unsigned long long` will hold it.

Comment: So will a `std::string`.

Comment: I have asked a [related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053113/is-c11s-long-long-really-at-least-64-bits). Basically, in c++(11) long long is the only portable way of holding such a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3000000^2 is less than 2^48, so an `uint64_t` from `cstdint` or `stdint.h` will hold your number with good margin.

Comment: For some reason when I try these datatypes, it does not output the correct number.

Comment: @WhatsInAName: Please update your question with some code that demonstrates the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: `^` is the bitwise xor operator.  C++ has no exponentiation operator

Comment: @WhatsInAName also, could you tell us what compiler you are using and whether it supports some c++11 features?

Answer (score 2):

The 64 bit integer:

```
long long int
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check with `std::numeric_limits`. In c++11, `long long` is a standard integer of at least 64 bits, so, for example, `unsigned long long` has these limits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>


int main() {
  std::cout << "sizeof : " << sizeof(unsigned long long) << "\n"; 
  std::cout << "min    : "<< std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::min() << "\n";
  std::cout << "max    : "<< std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() << "\n\n";
}
```

producing on my platform:

```
sizeof : 8
min    : 0
max    : 18446744073709551615
```

C++ provides various integer types, but as far as I know the 64 bit types were not mandated by the standard pre-c++11. I `long long` is the only standard integer to be at least 64 bits, so you would need a compiler with c++11 support. But it could be that your compiler supports some other non-standard 64 bit type.

Comment: I get the following msg: integer constant is too large for "long" type (when I try unsigned long long to store my number)

Comment: The problem could be that there was no "standard" 64 bit int before c++11, and maybe your compiler doesn't support c++11? What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "something like", it suggests that you are not actually sure how large the number is that you want to store.

Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) (say), and see which numeric type is best for your application.

Note that there is on 64-bit integer in that list; that's because it's not quite available everywhere.