# Why does the data type long support a maximum number equal to long long's?

Tags: c++

So I was doing some testing with the new data type **long long** when I stumbled upon a little "problem" (example came from C++ Primer 6th edition).  I was using the climits library to tell me the maximum number supported by **long** and **long long** and both came out to 9223372036854775807.  How is that possible?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <climits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "int size is " << sizeof(int) << " bytes." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "short size is " << sizeof(short) << " bytes." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "long size is " << sizeof(long) << " bytes." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "long long size is " << sizeof(long long) << " bytes." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Maximum values: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int: " << INT_MAX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "short: " << SHRT_MAX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "long: " << LONG_MAX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "long long: " << LLONG_MAX << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See this question for the *minimum* size required for each datatype: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc , note that it is the minimum size required i.e. the datatype can be bigger than the specified value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C99 standard specifies ranges of values each type must be able to represent (§5.2.4.2.1). The specified values are *minimum magnitude*, so nothing prevent from having bigger range. I converted this value to the least number of bits needed to represent number in these ranges on a digital computer.

- `int` should be at least 16 bits (range from –32,768 to 32,767)
- `long` should be at least 32 bits (range from –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647)
- `long` `long` should be at least 64 bits (range from –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

Comment: The C standard only specifies minimum value range (not bit width), but also this is a C++ tagged question.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis That's true. The C++11 standard refers to the C standard for that, though. Is there a way to represent an integer between -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 on less than 64 bits using a digital computer?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that; maybe it should be put in the answer. That range is certainly representable in at least 64 bits, but also in more. ;-)

Comment: @Antoine the C++ standard tries not to make assumptions about low level concepts such as bits. Not even the byte is defined in terms of bits.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Though there is `CHAR_BITS`.

Comment: @GManNickG but is the value of `CHAR_BITS` defined in the C++ standard? I was under the impression it wasn't, but my impressions are often wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It must be greater than eight, but otherwise no. I only meant to demonstrate that the standard does care about bits at some level.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible because the standard mandates that `long` has to be *at least* as large as `int` and `long long` has to be *at least* as large at `long` (**and** *at least* 64 bits in C++11). So there's no contradiction.

Concerning `long long` in C++11, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053113/is-c11s-long-long-really-at-least-64-bits).

Since you tagged the question C++, bear in mind that the numeric limits for a given type are given in the `limits` header, and that what is *standard* in C99 (i.e. what is in `<climits>`) is not necessarily standard in C++, i.e. it might be implementation defined. The number of bits in `long long` (or, more explicitly, its value range) is an example of a standard in `C` that only became standard in C++11.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are running on a 64-bit machine where the compiler implements 'long' and 'long long' as a 64-bit integer.

If you were to compile this on for a 32-bit machine you'd see a difference. For example:

```
$ g++ -m32 size.cpp
$ ./a.out 
int size is 4 bytes.
short size is 2 bytes.
long size is 4 bytes.
long long size is 8 bytes.
Maximum values: 
int: 2147483647
short: 32767
long: 2147483647
long long: 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Before C++11 the range of `long long` was not standard, so the results you print in your example would have been "implementation defined" and could well have been different.

Comment: Sure. It was just meant as an example. You really should be aware of how your compiler implements these. I remember using compilers where short and int were both 16-bit.

Comment: I agree completely! But if you want to write portable code it is good to know what is standard and what isn't.