# c++ maximum of number types

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [size of int, long, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc)
>   [Is `long` guaranteed to be at least 32 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329777/is-long-guaranteed-to-be-at-least-32-bits)

I wanted to find out maximum of each data type for my computer. the code is :

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << numeric_limits<int>::max() << endl;
    cout << numeric_limits<long>::max() << endl;
    cout << numeric_limits<long long>::max() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which prints:

```
2147483647
2147483647
9223372036854775807
```

question 1: why `int` and `long` are same?

question 2: above output is from VS2010 on 64bit. Is my c++ program running as 64bit?

Comment: There aren't any guarantees on the bit width apart from, I believe, `sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long long) >= sizeof(long)`.

Comment: Yes, your program may be running as a 64-bit executable, `int` is still 32 bit traditionally.

Comment: For backwards compatibility purposes, Microsoft chose to make longs the same size as ints in 64-bit programs.  We don't know if your program is 64-bit.  The max values for int, long and long long will be the same for 32- and 64-bit programs compiled by VS.

Comment: @chris: There is also the guarantee that `int` represent ±32,767, `long` represent ±2,147,483,647, and `long long` represent ±9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, I've been trying to find that in N3485, but can't. The link in the other question was a C draft. Is it still there in C++? It's a bit confusing because it even has this somewhere else: `constexpr long long_max()
{ return 2147483647; } // OK`

Comment: @chris: I thought the C++ spec guaranteed some certain compatibility with C and referred to the C spec.  For example, `std::printf()` is not actually defined in the C++ spec.  I don't know my way around the C++ spec though.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, I think it partially does, but I'm not sure what all is included in that.

Comment: @chris: In the section "numeric_limits members" it says `min()` is "Equivalent to `CHAR_MIN`, `SHRT_MIN`, `FLT_MIN`, `DBL_MIN`, etc."  Those are defined by reference to the C standard.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, Ah, a bit obfuscated imo, but thanks.

Comment: Related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053113/is-c11s-long-long-really-at-least-64-bits). In C++11 `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Comment: @chris:  There are *some* guarantees.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329777/is-long-guaranteed-to-be-at-least-32-bits)

Comment: @JohnDibling and juanchopanza, Thanks a lot. I never knew those questions existed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> question 1: why int and long are same?

For various reasons (convenience), sizes of integers supported by machine architectures tend to be powers of two.  Most modern processors can natively work with 8, 16, 32, and 64-bit integers.  However, there are five commonly used integer types: `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long`.  So two of them have to have the same size.

- On most 16-bit platforms, `int` and `short` are both 16-bit.
- On most 32-bit platforms, `int` and `long` are both 32-bit.
- On most 64-bit platforms, `long` and `long long` are both 64-bit.  There is one exception...

> question 2: above output is from VS2010 on 64bit. Is my c++ program running as 64bit?

Impossible to tell from this data.  Windows is the one platform where `long` and `int` have the same size for both 32-bit and 64-bit programs.

Answer (score 2):

They output the same because with Visual Studio, both `int` and `long` are signed 32-bit integers. This is true regardless of whether you're building a 64-bit or 32-bit binary (Windows 64-bit follows the [LLP64 model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models))

Because the size of `int` and `long` doesn't vary between 32-bit and 64-bit on visual studio, there's no way to tell which you're buinding from the data you've provided

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of a given type is compiler dependant.  The C++ standard does not state anything about a long having to be a specific number of bits etc.

However what is does state is that:

```
1 = sizeof(char)<=sizeof(short)<=sizeof(int)<=sizeof(long)<=sizeof(long long)
```

If you are looking to use a specific sized integer, I would suggest including "inttypes.h" and using the int_8t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, etc...

Comment: Actually, it guarantees that `sizeof(char) == 1`.  The standard also defines "byte" as "whatever `char` is", whether or not that happens to be 8 bits.

Comment: Neat, I did know the first part, the second part I was unaware of.  I fixed my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ standard long needs to be at least as large as an int. This means that long can also be the same size as an int, which then implies that the min and max for a long and int of the same type (signed or unsigned) can be equal.

More info (not just about long and int, but other types as well) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/271132/13760

Here is some more interesting reading: [Is `long` guaranteed to be at least 32 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329777/is-long-guaranteed-to-be-at-least-32-bits)

As far as question 2 is concerned, you need to check your project settings and see if you're building a Win32 or x64 executable.