# Are there platforms with C++ compiler and without 64-bit integers?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I'm intending to write a C++ library that I want to be cross-platform. I'm just wondering if I would have to allow for platforms that lack any 64-bit integer types.

I know that there are 8- or 16-bit embedded systems with C compilers that have 32-bit integers but lack 64-bit integers (e.g. MSP430, at least historically), but is that true for any C++ compilers for such systems?

Context: I'm actually wanting to port a [simple pseudo-random number generator](https://github.com/cmcqueen/simplerandom) C library of mine to C++. The C library mainly deals with 32-bit integers, but has some optional 64-bit API. Also the 32-bit code can do some internal calculations using 64-bit implementations (which are very simple), or alternatively using a 32-bit-only implementations (which are more complicated). The C headers have `#ifdef UINT64_C` to enable/disable the 64-bit APIs. The C files have `#ifdef UINT64_C` to select between 64-bit or 32-bit-only implementations of some functions. So, do I have to do the same for a C++ library, or is it a safe assumption that `uint64_t` is always available?

Comment: What is your concern? Whether you should use `int64_t` by default? or whether you can use `int64_t` (or equivalent) in parts of your library? There are platforms that have innefficient 64bit integer types, and while code can be made compile you might not want to cater for those systems...

Comment: Comeau is probably the place to look to find C++ compilers for funny platforms (including embedded systems).

Comment: "cross-platform" is a relative term.  You should really define the platforms which you want to support, then you can accurately make decisions about what you can and cannot do.  You have zero chance of covering them all.

Comment: It's a fairly specific question I'm asking. I realise it's hard to prove a negative (there are _no_ platforms lacking capability XYZ), but I hope that if anyone _does_ know of a platform where the C++ compiler doesn't have 64-bit integers, then they can say so here.

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete answer at this stage, but it's something...

### Boost C++ Libraries

I wondered what the Boost C++ libraries do about 64-bit, since they aim to be a set of high-quality multi-platform libraries. Looking through the code, I stumbled across

- `BOOST_HAS_LONG_LONG`
- `BOOST_HAS_INT64_T`
- `BOOST_HAS_MS_INT64`

That indicates that the Boost libraries try to make allowances for platforms lacking `long long` and/or `uint64_t`, and maybe having a Microsoft specific `__int64` type.

I want to investigate this in more detail. It would be good to find Boost documentation that explains all that.

### C++11

C++11 defines [`long long` as at least 64 bits](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#long-long). C99 had already done so. So any compilers targeting C99 and/or C++11 should support 64-bit integer types. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053113/is-c11s-long-long-really-at-least-64-bits) for some background.

Comment: `BOOST_HAS_INT64_T` is a red herring: it is only found inside one header, where it's unconditionally being defined immediately before being used. It is by definition _always_ defined in all sources that "depend" on it.