# What should be the exact size of for unsigned long long

Tags: c++, c, lint

What should be the exact `typedef` for `unsigned long long` ?
For example:

`typedef unsigned int uint32 ;`            //considering my machine reading
`typedef unsigned char byte ;`

So what is

`typedef unsigned long long  ______ ;`

Is it `uint64` or more than this?

Comment: None. Its size is not fixed to one value. There is only a requirement on its minimum size.

Comment: 8 bytes (64 bits) on most compilers.

Comment: `typedef unsigned long long int  uint64_t`

Comment: Why do you typedef int to 'uint32'? Isn't uint used for unsigned integers?

Comment: Please fix the `typedef int uint32 ;`, Some unsuspecting newbie will eventually copy/paste it into code somewhere.  Reminds me of code that's been seen in the wild that defines `TRUE` to be `0` and `FALSE` to be `1` by carelessly declaring them in  an enum.

Comment: See this C++ question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053113/is-c11s-long-long-really-at-least-64-bits

Comment: @nos You want multiplication, not division

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits in size. Thus, it is equivalent to `uint_least64_t`:

> typedef unsigned long long uint_least_64_t

Comment: Given current platforms, they are typically equivalent. An esoteric/future C compliant platform may have `unsigned long long` as 128-bit unsigned and `unsigned long` as a 64-bit unsigned. Such a system would not maintain that equivalent with `typedef unsigned long uint_least64_t;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned long long my_variable;
```

means **my_variable** is an unsigned integer value of 64 bits (or more)

you may find helpfult this too:

[How many bytes is unsigned long long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836329/how-many-bytes-is-unsigned-long-long)

```
unsigned long long
```

is a synonim of

```
unsigned long long int
```

that is defined as

```
typedef unsigned long long int uint64_t
```

see

[Standard Integer Types](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html)

Comment: `unsigned long long int` is not defined as `uint64_t`.  `uint64_t` _may_ be defined as `unsigned long long int`, the reverse is not specified by C.