# What's the limit of long long int ?

Tags: c++

I find numeric limits of long long int insufficient. Is there any other numeric type in C++ like big integer in java?

I stumbled upon this question recently and didn't knew how to tackle it.....
https://blog.codechef.com/2009/07/02/tutorial-for-small-factorials/

Comment: No there isn't any standard _bigint_ type. There are libraries supporting such thogh.

Comment: There are a few different "big int" options for `C++`. Maybe look at this one: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: Consider `double` or `decimal`.

Comment: @Zdenek: If `long long int` is too small, how would using a `double` help? It only supports all the integers up to 2^53 - 1 (after that, you start losing precision) --- which is less than the minimum that a `long long int` must support. And that's *assuming* `double` is IEEE 64-bit floating-point format (they could be 32-bit and non-IEEE, for example). Also, there is no `decimal` type in C.

Comment: You are assuming that OP needs to avoid underflow. That may not be the case. Any float can represent a larger span of numbers than an integer which may be what he needs. You are of course right in that a 64-bit float has only 53 bits of mantissa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

unsigned long long int is biggest integer type in standard C++ 
( it can hold numbers from 0 to 18 446 744 073 709 551 615 ), 
if you want bigger ones you may need to search for some bignum libraries like this:
http://www.ttmath.org/

Comment: The standard doesn't tell how big (or small) are the numbers it can hold.  This is implementation dependent and shall be verified with `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()`

Comment: @Christophe - the standard **does** require each integer type to cover a minimum range. Essentially, `unsigned long long` must be at least 64 bits wide.

Comment: @PeteBecker Looking while this is true for most implementation, C++ 3.9.1 (pt.2 and 3) does not guarantee 64 bits.  Can you provide any reference for this claim ?

Comment: @Christophe but still, unsigned long long int will be biggest integer value possible to store

Comment: @encoreleeet this i fully agree ! My only concern is about the max value, not its type

Comment: @Christophe - this "claim" comes in through the C11 standard, section 5.2.4.2.1.

Comment: @PeteBecker ok, [point taken !](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053113/is-c11s-long-long-really-at-least-64-bits): I did only check in C++ std.  But I'd still advise to use `numeric_limits` instead of using some hard coded value ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Type Name - **long long**

Bytes - **8**

Range of Values - **–9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807**

Ref: [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)

Comment: The OP didn't specify the compiler.  This is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the C++ library `<boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>`  for such problems.

For example:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cpp_int f = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        f *= i;
    cout << "100! = " << f << '\n';
}
```

This will give the output

```
100! = 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

To know more about C++ boost library, you can refer [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advanced-c-boost-library/)